# Disable or Bypass Firefox Safe Mode

Tags: firefox, selenium, automated-tests

I have a proprietary application for automated testing that I built here at work that uses Selenium WebDriver classes to test our applications. It uses Firefox, but sometimes, when a new browser is launched, Firefox will open in Safe Mode and display the Safe Mode dialog. This seems to happen completely randomly, i.e. I will set up twenty tests to run and at any point this might happen. There only one block code that can be executed from test to test to launch a new browser, so it isn't in the testing application. Is there a way to override, or bypass, the safe mode dialog when this happens?

I need to run regressions overnight a lot of the time and it's frustrating when I see that my tests have been hung because of this

Comment: I don't believe there is such a possibility. However, surely you should get to the bottom of *why* FF is opening in safe mode at *seemingly* random times? Is it reproducible on another machine? Is it just something that happens on your CI server (if you have one?) What version of Firefox? What version of Selenium?